# How to plot predicted and test values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot my predicted values and my test values. Here are the shapes of `y_pred` and `y_test` and the axis i want to set as the `xticks`

```
print(y_test.shape) --> (3650,)
print(y_pred.shape) --> (3650,)
print(X_test.shape) --> (3650, 12)
print(avo_sales.Date.shape) --> (18249,)
```

If i want to set the `avo_sales.Date` as the x-axes i don't know how if it's possible because shapes is not matched. Then i thought if i could set the `X_test['Date col']` but i think it would be complicated, also the X_test is already scaled. Is there any way i could plot `y_pred` and `y_test` with `avo_sales.Date` as the x-axes? Because if i plot without the x-axes passed, the plot is kind of messy and unreadable

This is the `y_test` plot

[image: This is the y_test]

I want it to look kind of like this plot (the target plot before i turn it into y and process it)

[image: the target plot before i turn it into y and process it]

Comment: When you processed it, you reduced its dimension. What did you do? What are you trying to represent? My guess is you are mistaking there, as I do not understand how plotting those Y on this X-axis will result in any better readability. One naive way would be to represent each point 5 times (your X-axis + 1 = 5*3650). You could also try to plot one point every 5 X-coordinate, to do so, you can create the (X,Y) tuple for every point and then use a scatter representation. The second method corresponds also to recreating the X-axis by sampling it with 1 point out of 5.

Comment: My (still sleepy) brain is trying to understand your setting : X_Test['Date Col'] refers to what, regarding to the avo_sales.Date ? A subset of it ? I mean, how did you split your dataset (train-test-pred in three equal parts is my wild guess) and what is exactly you avo_sales df ?

Comment: @SimonVanMachin i want it refers to refer to my date column. I split it into `test_train_split` then from the model i predicted and store it in `y_pred`, [this is df i'm using](https://www.kaggle.com/neuromusic/avocado-prices)

Comment: @Mathieu @Mathieu i splitted my train_test set, create variable to store the predict and i plot want to create plot for each of test and the pred values so from the plots i could compare how fit is the pred values to the test values. I'm trying to plot each of them (groupby('Date') separately with Date from the `df` column as the x-axes(if possible), I'm trying to plot each of them more readable than the `y_test` plot.

Comment: @Mathieu For the AveragePrice plot that has Date as x-axes i actually made it like this `dategroup = avo_sales.groupby('Date').mean() plt.figure(figsize=(12,5)) plt.title('AveragePrices in dates') dategroup.AveragePrice.plot(x = avo_sales.Date)`

Comment: @Mathieu I'm sorry i forgot to mention it in my question, i mean if there's any way i could `groupby(Date)` the `y_test` and `y_pred` so the plot will be readable just like the plot below?